# R: Access/store optimal number of lags from unit root test

Tags: r, unit-root, lags

I am testing several variables for unit roots via the `ur.df` (from `urca` package) and `CADFtest` (from `CADFtest` package) functions. Both packages have functions allow to select the optimal number of lags via information criteria. While the resulting number of lags is visible in the test output, I would like to store them as a factor (to later summarize the results for all variables in an output matrix). However, when I try using the slot function, the following errors come up:

**urca** (with a maximum of 14 lags and automatic lag order selection through the AIC):

```
x <- ur.df(myvar$var1, lags = 14, selectlags = "AIC")
```

=> `x@lags` = 14 (i.e. the maximum number of lags, although only 12 lags are used). If I don't include `lags = 14`, the automatic selection no longer works and `x@lags` = 1.

**CADF** (with a maximum of 14 lags and automatic lag order selection through the AIC):

```
x <- CADFtest(myvar$var1, max.lag.y = 14, criterion = "AIC")
```

=> `x@lags` yields the error message

> "Error: trying to get slot "lags" from an object (class "CADFtest") that is not an S4 object"

Is there a way to either fix the `@lags` slot for `urca` or implement a similar function for `CADFtest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `CADFtest` does not return S4 class object. It uses S3 classes, which in this case means that the result is a list with class attribute set to `c("CADFtest","htest")`. To see the names of the elements of this list use function `names`. You can access them either using `$` or `[[` notation. Probably `x$max.lag.y` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you so so much, mpiktas, that solves it!!